# About the "knower" disappearing during vipassana

Tags: personal-practice, theravada, vipassana

When inner conversation disappears, the "doer" disappears. How does the "knower" disappear, during vipassana meditation?

Answer (score 1):

Knower dissapears when "knowing" disappears.

How to achieve this?

Complicated answer is: with stopping craving.

Simple answer is: with calming of the mind and letting go completely.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction between idea and experience falls away. Samsara and Nibbana are actually seen / known to be one thing. It just happens. Concepts and questions no longer hold one's attention for long.